# How to verify that an SCP file upload was successful

Tags: c#, file, ftp, scp

I've been given an assignment to use SCP to upload a file to a Secure FTP Server (I'm doing this using Workflow Foundation activities).  I can upload the file OK, but I need to do some sort of validation to make sure that the file is, in fact, there.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Chew

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question? What have you tried? Are you confident this isn't already answered? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this type of problem before by:

- uploading the file to the server.
- downloading it as a *different* file name.
- running a local comparison of the two files.

A script to do this is relatively easy to set up.